# how to split output from pipe into variables by using "\n\n" instead of "\n" with while contruct?

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a data file that is in this format:

```
name=...
phone=...
address=..

name=...
phone=..
address=...

name=...
phone=...
address=...
```

and I've tried to use while loop for that to split it into chunks where there is a blank line that is "\n\n". But this approach below fails.

```
cat mydatafile.txt | while read row; do
  echo $row
  # process the data
done
```

Wanted end state is a variable that contains three lines of content from file, that is `row="name=...\nphone=...\naddress=..."` in every iteration of the loop.

Comment: What's the wanted output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you're 100% certain there will always be 3 lines that you want and then 1 unneeded line you could do something like this:

```
cat mydatafile.txt | while read row1; do
  read row2
  read row3
  read junk
  row="$row1 $row2 $row3"
  echo $row
  # process the data
done
```

I *think* that will continue to `read` from the same stdin, but I'm not 100% certain.

Or you could create your own finite state automaton (sorry - I just love the sound of that):

```
recno=0
cat mydatafile.txt | while read foo; do
  let recno=recno+1
  if [ $recno -lt 4 ]
  then
    row="$row $foo"
  fi
  if [ $recno == 4 ]
  then
    echo $row
    # process the data
    recno=0
    row=''
  fi
done
# Here you might want to check that you've processed the last data...
```

If you want to use a blank line to determine the start of a new row it would look something like this (modifying the 2nd solution):

```
cat mydatafile.txt | while read foo; do
  if [ -z "$foo" ]
  then
    echo $row
    # process the data
    row=''
  else
    row="$row $foo"
  fi
done
# Here you NEED to process the last row unless the file ended in a blank line
```

Comment: That's nice, but how about unknown number of lines in a row ?

Comment: blank line indicates the change between rows?

Comment: I like the second solution! +1

Comment: @PeterBowers: yes, blank line is the delimiter.

Comment: So did my final edited answer solve it for you, @rsk82?

Answer (score 0):

This is more suited to awk with a custom record separator:

```
awk -v RS='\n\n' 'NF{printf "row=[%s]\n", $0}' file
row=[name=...
phone=...
address=..]
row=[name=...
phone=..
address=...]
row=[name=...
phone=...
address=...]
```

`-v RS='\n\n'` sets record separator as 2 new lines and then `$0` gives you all the data of a block.

[Working Demo](http://ideone.com/HHvszv)

Comment: I get: `row=[name=]
row=[phone=]
row=[address=]`

Comment: Worked fine for me, @alfasin. It *does* leave the newlines in - not sure if that is the expected behavior or not... Oh, yes - re-reading the OP question he does want the `\n` left in.

Comment: Not sure why, but it doesn't work for me: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6086504/1__cass_stream_euprod_cass-stream-eu--euwest1a-i-dd311938____bash_.png

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
str=""
while read row
do
    if (($i % 4 == 0 ))
    then
        echo $str
        # process $str
        str=""
    else
        str="$str\n$row"
    fi
    i=$(($i+1))
done < "mydatafile.txt"
```